# Dynamic Method Dispatch in java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

```
class A{
int a=10;   
public void show(){ 
    System.out.println("Show A: "+a);
    }
}

class B extends A{
public int b=20;    
public void show(){
    System.out.println("Show B: "+b);
    }
}



public class DynamicMethodDispatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    A aObj = new A();       
    aObj.show();    //output - 10

    B bObj = new B();
    bObj.show();   //output - 20

    aObj = bObj;   //assigning the B obj to A..         
    aObj.show();  //output - 20 

    aObj = new B();
    aObj.show();  //output - 20
             System.out.println(bObj.b);  //output - 20 
    //System.out.println(aObj.b); //It is giving error



     }
}
```

In the above program i'm getting Error wen i try invoking **aObj.b**.
                1.why i'm not able to acess that variable through the aObj though it is refering to class B??
                 2. why i'm able to acess the method show()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to distinguish between the **static type** of `aObj` and the **runtime type** of `aObj`.

Code such as

```
A aObj = new B();
```

results in an `aObj` variable with static type `A` and runtime type `B`.

The compiler will only bother too look at the *static type* when deciding what to allow or not.

To your questions:

> 1.why i'm not able to acess that variable through the aObj though it is refering to class B??

Because there is (in general) no way for the compiler to *know* that `aObj` will refer to a `B` object at runtime, only that it will refer to some form of `A` object. Since `.b` is not available on all `A` objects, so the compiler will think *"better safe than sorry"* and disallow it.

> 2.why i'm able to acess the method show()?

Because this method *is* available in all `A` objects (if it's not declared in the subclass, it is still inherited from `A`).

Comment: The first 4 lines of your answer were invaluable for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`aObj` is a local variable of type `A`. `A` has no member called `b`, that's only in your subclass `B`. If you want to use `b`, you need to declare a variable of type `B`, but of course you can only assign it instances of `B` (or subclasses if there are any).

`A` declares a method `show()`, but you override the implementation in your subclass `B`.

Comment: But How it is accessing the show() of B?

    aObj = bObj;
    aObj.show();  //output - 20 which is the value of b

Comment: A declares a method `show()`, but you override the implementation in your subclass `B`. You probably should look into the concepts of OO/inheritance a bit further.

Comment: Ya.. i got it..Yes., i'm really poor in opp principles.. Where to read the OOP principle? recommend some good sites.. Thanks

Comment: i didnt do it dude... Belive me..  I don have sufficient points to do tat also.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is known as `virtual method invocation`, and it is an important aspect of `polymorphism` in Java. You should have a look at this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

Answer (score 0):

Methods and fields have different polymorphic behaviour.

The method that will be called is the method of the run time type of the instance

```
aObj=new B(); //new B()
```

The field that will be called is the field of the type of reference that you declared

```
A aObj = new A(); // A aObj
```

The following would work even is there was no show() method in A.

```
aObj = new B();
aObj.show(); //calls B's show()
```

Comment: I checked out the example in JAVA, if i try A aobj=new B() and then aobj.show(), then compiler gives error asking me to define method show() in A

Answer (score 0):

```
class A{ // class A has variable a and method show();
int a=10;   
public void show(){ 
    System.out.println("Show A: "+a);
    }
}

class B extends A{ //class B inherits variables and methods of A.
   // so class B has variable a, b and show(). Also, show is overridden by class B.
public int b=20;    
public void show(){
    System.out.println("Show B: "+b);
    }
}
```

1. since A doesn't have variable b inside it, even when u are passing B to A, you still have A object which does not have variable b inside it. So, trying to access b will give you compile time error.
2. in case of show(), A and B both have this method, so what you are doing here is actually overriding it at runtime. This is nothing but [Polymorphism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm). So since A already has method show(), and it is overridden later by B,

A a = new B();
a.show();

this will run the show() method of B at runtime.