# How to resolve issue between Interface and Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I am facing a confusion. please look into the below java code.

```
public interface Interface {

    public void draw();
}

public class A {

    public void draw()
    {
        System.out.println("Draw in A");
    }
}

public class B extends A implements Interface {

    @Override
    public void draw()
    {
        System.out.println("Draw in B");
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Interface i = new B();
        i.draw();

        A a = new B();
        a.draw();

        B b  = new B();
        b.draw();
    }
}
```

For all I am getting the same output ("Draw in B"). Could you please tell me which draw() is getting invoked (Interface / Parent class)?

Comment: You're always creating new instances of class `B`, that is why `B`s version of `draw` is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595527/dynamic-method-dispatch-in-java

Comment: My confusion is that, if draw() method of class B is ovrerriding the draw() method of class A or implementing the draw() method of the Interface.

Answer (score 12):

Java performs [*late binding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding), meaning it is the method of the *instance* that gets invoked, not the method corresponding to the type.

```
A a = new B();
^         ^
type      instance
```

In this case, you create only `B` instances (`new B()`), so the method of `B` gets invoked each time, irrespective of your assigning this instance to a variable of type `A`.

See also: [*dynamic dispatch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch)

Comment: My confusion is that, if draw() method of class B is ovrerriding the draw() method of class A or implementing the draw() method of the Interface.

Comment: @SusantaMondal It's doing both.

Answer (score 4):

The method which is invoked depends on the Object created. So, the method of the RHS (`B`) is invoked always.

Comment: My confusion is that, if draw() method of class B is ovrerriding the draw() method of class A or implementing the draw() method of the Interface.

Comment: @SusantaMondal - It doesn't matter. Why?. Because the method of the `object` i.e, `B` is invoked during runtime.

Answer (score 4):

As you might have guessed, it is the draw() method in class B that is getting invoked. This is because even though you have declared the varialbles i, a, and b as being able to reference different type, you choose to assign instances of type B to all of them. In other words, when draw is invoked what matters is the runtime type of the object (the one created by new B()), and not how the variable is declared.

Comment: My confusion is that, if draw() method of class B is ovrerriding the draw() method of class A or implementing the draw() method of the Interface.

Comment: It is doing both actually. Since the method signature is the same the implemented method in class B can function as both an implementation of draw in the the interface and a new overriding implementation of the method draw in class A.

Answer (score 1):

every time you create instance of B class, and its method is being invoked

Comment: My confusion is that, if draw() method of class B is ovrerriding the draw() method of class A or implementing the draw() method of the Interface.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple words it is because of `new B()`. it doesnt matter what type it is, when you instantiating from `B`, all methods from `B`(and it's parents if B not implementing them.) will be invoked.

Comment: My confusion is that, if draw() method of class B is ovrerriding the draw() method of class A or implementing the draw() method of the Interface.