# Dynamic dispatch and type checking mechanism in Java

Tags: java, oop, vtable, duck-typing, dynamic-dispatch

I would like to understand how an object in java is internally represented consisting of "pointers" to fields and to functions in vtables and how these internal representations change when there are assignments, implicit casts and explicit casts done, and how the static and dynamic type checking works.

Consider an example extended from: [Dynamic Method Dispatch in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595527/dynamic-method-dispatch-in-java)

```
class A{
int a=10;   
public void show(){ 
    System.out.println("Show A: "+a);
    }
}

class B extends A{
public int b=20;    
public void show(){
    System.out.println("Show B: "+b);
    }
}

class C extends B{
public int c=30;    
public void show(){
    System.out.println("Show B: "+c);
    }
}
```

How are objects constructed in the memory? What happens when there is an assignment (or equivalently parameter passed)? What is the difference in the memory-represenation of the object in the following cases?

```
B bObj = new B();

A aObj = new B();

C cObj = new B();
```

What happens in the memory-representation when there is explicit up/down casting? How does it check if such a cast is allowed and how does it change the internal representation and method call dispatching information.

```
((A) new A()).show()
((A) new B()).show()
((A) new C()).show()

((B) new A()).show()
((B) new B()).show()
((B) new C()).show()

((B) new A()).show()
((B) new B()).show()
((B) new C()).show()

((A) xObj).show() //xObj being say an unknown object
((B) xObj).show()
((C) xObj).show()

((C) ((A) new B())).show()
```

I've looked for sources on these topics but haven't found any good one. If the topic is too broad it would be helpful if I could be given a direction towards where I can study this.

Comment: If you're asking about slicing "when there is explicit up/down casting" then I don't think that happens at all.  Java objects are never sliced.  Java uses `invoke_virtual` which finds the correct method to invoke, with out altering the memory of the object.  There's also no dynamic dispatch in Java, it's all based on object type (and not in your examples based on casting when you up cast).

Comment: It's late, I got confused between dynamic dispatch and double dispatch.  There's no double dispatch in Java.  I'm unclear if dynamic dispatch is the same as virtual methods and overriding.  Java has the latter, for sure.